# What are the minimum historical changes that would permit the use of Tanks at the beginning of World War I? (Central Powers)

Tags: science-based, warfare, alternate-history

What are the minimum historical changes that would permit the use of Tanks at the beginning of World War I for the central powers, so that they accomplish the following requisites:

1. It should be maintained a heavy protected secret of state.
2. And end the World War I for Chrismas, if it starts in September.

Bonus: How many tanks would be required?

#### Edit

Bonus: If you were a time traveler that come back to convince the K. Wilhelm II to produce Tanks. How do you would convince him that they are needed?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130954/discussion-on-question-by-erdel-von-mises-what-are-the-minimum-historical-change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Two divisions of Panzer Is**

What you need, at a minimum, is the Panzer I.  Something fast, reliable, and relatively cheap.  The WWI era tanks produced by the british/french/germans would NOT have won the war by Christmas in 1914.  The main reason being they were too slow.  To achieve a true breakthrough your tank must out-pace infantry, and a WWI-era tank simply couldn't. They were also wildly unreliable, with the majority of tanks being taken out by mechanical breakdown or bogging (getting stuck), often before engaging the enemy!  With an off-road speed of 16 MPH, a range of 100-120 miles, and two machineguns, Panzer Is in sufficient quantity could get the job done.

So, what do you need for a Panzer I?  First the steel production.  Germany has it, but without handwaving extra manufacturing capability you'll need to cut down on the Kriegsmarine.  This serves the dual function of getting Great Britain off Germany's back, as the increase in the German Navy was a major reason the UK started its alliance with France.  Though they may still come in over Belgium. A Panzer I weighs 5.4 tons per the wiki, so call it 5 tons of steel per tank.

Next you'll need *somebody* to approve of tanks.  Given Kaiser Wilhelm's historical... let's say flightyness, as well as his love of new fancy war machines, it's not beyond the realm of possibility that he could become enamored of an inventor's bright shiny toy in the same way he did with the machinegun. (which was a major reason germany started the war with more-per-battalion than the other Great Powers.)   If the All-highest wanted two of his Guards Cavalry divisions to ride "iron horses" into a charge like the "Teutonic Knights of Old" the German army would probably oblige him.  Especially if it came at the expense of the Kriegsmarine!

You'l also need some jumps of capability for precision machine tooling to produce an engine capable of MOVING multi-ton vehicles rapidly and reliably.  I'm not an engineer but seeing as how you'd need doctrine and vehicles in place by 1914 you're talking tech roughly 30 years ahead of its time (the Panzer I's design began in 1932, and you'd want at least a decade to design/produce/equip/train). That's a nontrivial advance, especially when it comes to the engine's power to weight ratio.  But at the very least you need something on treads that's bulletproof and can reliably move faster than a man can run, and be operational for weeks without major overhauls.  Which again is far and away more than even the best WWI tanks could manage.

So you've done it! You created a Panzer I-equivalent.  How many do you need? My guess (and we can do no more than that) would be 300 in two divisions.  The plan would be for these divisions to spearhead the German First and Second armies, which have the furthest to go in the Schlieffen Plan.  Immune to infantry and machineguns, you'd probably still lose most of them to excellent french 75mm field artillery.  But given the french were trying to engage "over open sights" and the speed of the tanks, hopefully you'd be able to use them to get far enough along to finish the encirclement of the french armies and make it work.  There is one problem though....

LOGISTICS.  A Tank needs, at a bare minimum, fuel and ammo.  Spare parts as well.  And in 1914 the german army (indeed all the world's armies) are incapable of providing it.  So you'd ALSO need to invest heavily into motorized transport so your supplies could keep up with your tanks.  And trained mechanics, and supplies and fuels for the trucks.  Which ostensibly the german army could pull off. The Imperial German Army's best minds went into their Strategic Railroad units, and providing the two Armored Divisions with those guys could sort out the logistics problems.  Provided you designed/built/trained the supply units.

If all this works, and you take Paris before Christmas and the french capitulate, you still have the British and Russians to deal with.  Quite frankly they may do a negotiated peace, and really they'd have to if you want the war over by Christmas.  Russia is simply to big, with too large an army, for even the most ridiculous "plausible" handwavium to utterly defeat them by Christmas 1914.    The British, if they were involved, will have lost the majority of their regular army, but the  territorials that fought the war in 1915 would still be there (having been en-route at the start of the war not on the field in france) and all the tanks ever made wouldn't force the english channel. However if the Germans agreed to return Belgium the Brits might do a deal.  it'd CERTAINLY collapse the government of 1914 to be humiliated in such a fashion, but since we're playing what-ifs....

Comment: "getting Great Britain off Germany's back, as the increase in the German Navy was a major reason the UK started its alliance with France." It is no true, British are doing divide and conquer in continental Europe, they are back Germany, when they should have allied with Germany.

Comment: British did no enter the War because Belgium, it was just the pretext to the public opinion. But if Belgium is free they will have no longer pretext and if the war continues they may have revolts.

Comment: It's also worth noting that when one is _not_ on a war footing, keeping the kind of precision tooling needed confined to Germany is nigh-impossible.  Even leaving aside industrial espionage, it can often be enough for a tech base simply to know that something is _possible_ for them to start reproducing it.

Answer (score 4):

**AT LAST FOUR MAJOR CHANGES WOULD BE NEEDED**

The idea of tanks existed long before WW1, but no need was seen for them before the massive deaths in WW1 trench warfare. So I imagine that a minor war somewhere in the early 20th century, with trench warfare, could have projected the need. This would be the first change needed.

However, even if just one European power saw the need, it is doubtful that very many could be built (and tested) in secret - the resources, manpower and money required would be too great. The second change would be that a power somehow would have the money and resources to produce an army of tanks over a few years - and not use these resources for anything else. The third change would be that the power somehow had to capability to do so in secret, despite the resources and manpower required. Basically, anybody involved would have to keep quiet, and the construction and testing would have to take place in a very remote place - and nobody should wonder why all these people and materials suddenly need to go to this place.

A fourth change would be a lot of very sudden advances in technology. The tanks that were deployed in WW1 were far too primitive to be able to roll all over Europe in a week. I doubt that even moving non-stop along perfect roads with good refueling stations, they would not be able to cover this distance in a week. Even WW2 tanks would be hard pressed to accomplish this. So at least one super-brilliant scientist with a large team of super-brilliant engineers dedicated to this project (and no other, such as developing better guns or airplanes) would be required.

It is impossible to guess at the number of tanks required, since it depends on their speed, maneuverability and firepower. Roughly 7,000 tanks were produced during WW1, and probably at least this many would be required for a rapid, total victory. Fuel reserves to run all these tanks thousands of km would also need to be stockpiled, which would be difficult, especially in secret, but not impossible.

Any one of these changes would likely be possible at a stretch - but for all of them to be possible, we would enter the realm of science fantasy. But if you think you can make it believable, go for it.

Comment: I will below the time requeriments to start in september, end in December.

Comment: Also I added  a Bonus

Comment: I'm inclined to agree with Klaus - the time restrictions and secrecy restrictions would make this impossible IRL, and in magic fantasyland, implausible.  Particularly secrecy.  Spycraft was really quite good preceding WWI.

Answer (score 3):

Personally I think that you wouldn't have to change too much - all it would take is a forward thinking individual that is able to convince their patron country that tanks will be important.

A big fallacy at the beginning of World War I was that it could be fought no differently from recent wars. This was a very pervasive feeling at the time, and a reason why the powers just kept on laying down hundreds and hundreds and thousands of soldiers down on the sacrificial altar - they were certain they just had to make a push and the war would end.

But as with everything in history, there were people who knew better, who were forward thinking. Put this person in the position where they can demonstrate how gruesome the maxim gun is ten years earlier or something, and that something like a tank is sorely needed. You could even have it be something spread across all the powers if something like an influential writer declared "any army that does not have a modern roman shield formation will be shot to pieces" it could have a great affect.

I believe this is something that happened with a push around the world to modernize naval power.

Unless I am mistaken, the technology to create tanks was not something prohibitive, it was just the motivation to create them. The conceptual idea of tanks dates back centuries earlier even. If there were any problem with tanks having a meaningful role in World War I, I am certain it would be their reliability -  something that was still quite difficult with tanks in the second world war.

Comment: Bonus: If you were a time traveler that come back to convince the K. Wilhelm II to produce Tanks. How do you would convince him that they are needed?

Comment: I gave the example of some kind of demonstration with a maxim gun. The people of the late 19th and early 20th century had a pension for showmanship it seemed - one of the ways Edison attempted to show how awful Tesla's alternating current was was by electrocuting a man with it, killing elephants, etc. 

It would be a gory thing for the time to round up a bunch of stray dogs, release them, and then all gun them down with a machine gun. Then you stroll up to your customer and say, now, my invention, the tank, is exactly what you need.... then do a demonstration of a tank being unaffected.

Comment: "the technology to create tanks was not something prohibitive" - have you looked at the tanks WW1 technology produced? They were slow-moving, poorly armed, and their mechanical systems were underpowered and unreliable. All of these problems needed years of focused attention to even begin to fix.

Comment: @Cadence and I prefaced that with "unless I am mistaken," which I felt I might be. I knew that the tanks would be rather primitive, but if they had been used from the outset of the war perhaps the issues could have been fixed enough that they actually had a noticeable effect.

Comment: @WasatchWind Possibly, but there wouldn't be much for them to do at the outset of the war, when there were rapid maneuvers being made. It was only once the trenches were already laid that the niche of "super-slow but bulletproof" became valuable enough to pour resources into.

Comment: Coulf you explore more the tech part?